# MySQL - Getting max ID from GROUP BY and maintaining performance

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables:

Post, Thread, and Subforum.

A Subforum has many Threads,
and a Thread has many Posts.

I'm trying to retrieve the latest (max ID for now) Post in each Subforum.

This is what I've tried so far:

```sql
SELECT 
    p1.id,
    p1.thread_id,
    Subforums.id as subforum_id
FROM Posts p1 LEFT JOIN Posts p2
    ON (p1.thread_id = p2.thread_id AND p1.id < p2.id)
LEFT JOIN Threads
    ON p1.thread_id = Threads.id 
    AND p2.thread_id = Threads.id
LEFT JOIN Subforums 
    ON Threads.subforum_id = Subforums.id
WHERE p2.id IS NULL
```

And it gives me a table like this:

```
id | thread_id | subforum_id
12 | 1         | 4
...
```

I understand that I could use a combination of MAX and GROUP BY statements to get the max `id` per `subforum_id`, but that is looking like it's not performant at all.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a subquery that orders by `Post.id DESC` and `LIMIT` to 1 result:

```sql
SELECT 
  s.id as subforum_id, 
  (
    SELECT 
      p.id 
    FROM 
      Posts p 
      LEFT JOIN Threads t ON p.thread_id = t.id 
    WHERE 
      s.id = t.subforum_id 
    ORDER BY 
      p.id DESC 
    LIMIT 
      1
  ) AS latest_post_id 
FROM 
  Subforums s;
```

[Live example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p3ozMc8ZRRJcVqo8mdbrjs/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it will do a full table scan of Posts table, and therefore yes, not performant. Felipe Zavan's solution looks better but is incomplete with the results you are looking for. Assuming id is the primary key on Posts, then it will be indexed and I would do

```
SELECT 
p1.id,
p1.thread_id,
Subforums.id as subforum_id
FROM (select thread_id, max(id) as id from Posts group by thread_id) as p1
LEFT JOIN Threads
    ON p1.thread_id = Threads.id 
LEFT JOIN Subforums 
    ON Threads.subforum_id = Subforums.id
```